# Why google doesn't use data class for DefaultButtonColors?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Why google doesn't use data class for `DefaultButtonColors` ?
Is there any reason ? Any problem that can happen if they were using a data class ?

```
@Immutable
private class DefaultButtonColors(
    private val backgroundColor: Color,
    private val contentColor: Color,
    private val disabledBackgroundColor: Color,
    private val disabledContentColor: Color
) : ButtonColors {
    @Composable
    override fun backgroundColor(enabled: Boolean): State<Color> {
        return rememberUpdatedState(if (enabled) backgroundColor else disabledBackgroundColor)
    }

    @Composable
    override fun contentColor(enabled: Boolean): State<Color> {
        return rememberUpdatedState(if (enabled) contentColor else disabledContentColor)
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || this::class != other::class) return false

        other as DefaultButtonColors

        if (backgroundColor != other.backgroundColor) return false
        if (contentColor != other.contentColor) return false
        if (disabledBackgroundColor != other.disabledBackgroundColor) return false
        if (disabledContentColor != other.disabledContentColor) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = backgroundColor.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + contentColor.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + disabledBackgroundColor.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + disabledContentColor.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: data classes have some issues like size increase - https://medium.com/bumble-tech/data-classes-in-kotlin-the-real-impact-of-using-it-6f1fdc909837. It may be a reason.

Comment: Maybe. But they override `equals` and `hashCode`. So, according to this Medium, they only save size for `toString`.

Comment: https://jakewharton.com/public-api-challenges-in-kotlin/

Comment: Interesting. It could be to avoid backwards-incompatible changes.